Prince is in arranged marriage and bride is sobbing through whole thing
The prince is one of the two main characters who are in love, and it's at the hopeless point of the romantic movie. He's about to marry a woman (noblewoman or princess, I'm not sure) in an arranged marriage which neither of them want. 
The woman is sobbing through the wedding and speaking in a non-English language (I think it might have been Spanish?), and when the prince calls it off she is thrilled and runs to her lover, who is in the church watching and he leaves to go find the woman he's actually in love with.
Edit: It's a live action movie, fairly recent (definitely in colour), and I don't remember if it was American or British. 

Sounds like EverAfter with Drew Barrymore from 1998. From IMDb:

With the sudden death of her loving father, Danielle is made a servant by her new stepmother. She also has two new stepsisters, one quite kind but the other one really horrid. Still, Danielle grows up to be a happy and strong-willed young lady, and one day her path crosses that of handsome Prince Henry, who has troubles of his own at home.

The prince is supposed to marry a Spanish princess, but she sobs throughout the wedding ceremony because she, like him, is in love with someone else. The prince finally calls it all off and allows her to immediately run to her true love, who was in church. Here's the trailer:



